# Dificultad con función

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, funciones

### Tengo esta funcion:

Lo que hace es recibir como argumento un formato json generado en `funcion_principal`.

```
def blade_runner(respuesta):
    if 'entities' in respuesta:
        if 'br_answer:br_answer_celdas' in respuesta['entities']:
            valor= respuesta['entities']['br_answer:br_answer_celdas']
            if valor[0]['body'] == 'celdas':
                print("Celdas")
                funcion_principal()


        elif 'br_answer:br_answer_interconectados' in respuesta['entities']:
            valor= respuesta['entities']['br_answer:br_answer_interconectados']
            if valor[0]['body']== 'interconectadas':
                print("Interconectadas")
                funcion_principal()
```

Cuando se ejecuta el codigo y se le pasa el valor `'celdas'` funciona perfectamente y mientras siga pasando lo mismo sigue funcionando. El problema viene cuando paso el valor `'interconectadas'`, en este caso no ocurre nada.

### El formato json que se pasa en cada uno de los casos son estos:

Este es el formato json de la parte del codigo que **SI** se ejecuta.

```
{
   "text":"celdas",
   "intents":[
      {
         "id":"2884367285179006",
         "name":"blade_runner_test",
         "confidence":0.9747
      }
   ],
   "entities":{
      "br_answer:br_answer_celdas":[
         {
            "id":"485561362587921",
            "name":"br_answer",
            "role":"br_answer_celdas",
            "start":0,
            "end":6,
            "body":"celdas",
            "confidence":0.9425,
            "entities":[
               
            ],
            "value":"celdas",
            "type":"value"
         }
      ]
   },
   "traits":{
      
   }
}
```

Este es el formato json de la parte del código que **NO** se ejecuta.

```
{
   "text":"interconectadas",
   "intents":[
      {
         "id":"2884367285179006",
         "name":"blade_runner_test",
         "confidence":0.9922
      }
   ],
   "entities":{
      "br_answer:br_answer_interconectados":[
         {
            "id":"258996879266618",
            "name":"br_answer",
            "role":"br_answer_interconectados",
            "start":0,
            "end":15,
            "body":"interconectadas",
            "confidence":0.9638,
            "entities":[
               
            ],
            "value":"interconectadas",
            "type":"value"
         }
      ]
   },
   "traits":{
      
   }
}
```

> Cabe recalcar que no es un archivo en json el que se manda si no solo el formato, creo, no estoy muy seguro de esto pero en ningún momento he creado un archivo json.

## Actualización

Lo que hice fue dividir las condiciones en funciones diferentes y llamando a esa función dependiendo `blade_runner` en primer lugar. No es una solución real a mi problema pero al menos hace lo que esperaba:')

¡Muchas gracias por su apoyo!

Comment: Intenta poner un ```elif``` después del ```if``` en el evaluas interconectadas e imprime ```valor```

Comment: @christian hola, me temo que no entendi:(

Comment: Ok voy a poner una respuesta para explicarme mejor

Answer (score 0):

Haz un print en ambos casos para ver el resultado y saber que valor es el que esta entrando al if

```
if valor[0]['body']== 'interconectadas':
     print("Interconectadas")
     funcion_principal()
else:
     print(valor)
```

Comment: Lo hice con un `else` por que no supe que poner en el `elif`. No imprimio nada. Ese es el dilema, no entra en ese condicional. Hice un print en el valor de `'celdas'` e imprimo el formato json de interconectadas. No se porque no funciona.

Comment: Osea en ```celdas``` te aparece lo de ```interconectadas```?

Comment: Exactamente, ni idea porque...
Corrección: ya vi que no entra a `celdas` solo lo ignora. Lo que me imprimió fue: `[{'id': '485561362587921', 'name': 'br_answer', 'role': 'br_answer_celdas', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'body': 'celdas', 
'confidence': 0.9425, 'entities': [], 'value': 'celdas', 'type': 'value'}]`

Comment: Ok, edita tu pregunta y pon lo que descubriste. Mañana lo reviso con tranquilidad.

Comment: Tu código está mal indentado, por favor corrígelo. Además sería bueno dar una explicación un poco más extensa, decir: *"haz esto para ver que pasa"* hace parecer que no estás seguro de que tu código funcione. Puedes leer [answer]. Saludos